# Convert pandas dataframe with missing values from object to int

Tags: pandas, dtype

I am trying to change the values in the data frame below to ints so I can changes these times hh/mm/ss into a number value based on hours (e.g. for row two hrs_cor would equal 5.5).

```
         hrs  mins  secs
0         None  None
1         None  None
2      5    30    00
3      5    22    30
4      8    00    00
...   ..   ...   ...
1052      None  None
1053      None  None
1054      None  None
1055      None  None
1056      None  None
```

The issue I am running is converting the data frame into numeric values, and I think it is due to the empty cells. So far I have tried variations of the code below:

```
MID_calc['hrs'] = MID_calc.to_numeric(MID_calc['hrs'], errors='coerce').astype('INT46')
```

And this error is returned:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numeric'
```

Currently, all values are objects

```
hrs     object
mins    object
secs    object
dtype: object
```

I have looked through several posts, but nothing seems to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
import pandas as pd

MID_calc['hrs']  = pd.to_numeric(MID_calc['hrs'] , errors='ignore').astype('INT46')
```

dont just copy the code directly from the website. Understand what it does.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my typo (fixed above). I had tried several different codes that made sense, and this was one example I was retyping quickly. Your solution returns the same error. Even when pd is renamed as the correct dataframe name.

Comment: @StephenJ.SussChacón `pd` is not a dataframe name. You must be doing something wrong. Also check the edit and try again

Comment: when I change 'INT64' to 'Int64'